# Displaying dynamic content in webview UWP

Tags: webview, windows-runtime, uwp

I want to display product specification from an external service. To do that I have to pass the below JS string to Webview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

   <div id="flix-minisite"></div>
<div id="flix-inpage"></div>
<script
type="text/javascript"
src="http://media.flixfacts.com/js/loader.js"
data-flix-distributor="12612"
data-flix-language="id"
data-flix-brand="Samsung"
data-flix-mpn="UA55JU6600KPXD"
data-flix-ean=""
data-flix-sku=""
data-flix-button="flix-minisite"
data-flix-inpage="flix-inpage"
data-flix-button-image=""
data-flix-fallback-language="e2"
data-flix-price=""
async>
</script>
</body>         </html>
```

I've added the below method:

```
webview.NavigateToString("htmlString");
```

Adding this just displays the text from the service, but the images and videos are not getting displayed.

Expected result : 
http://media.flixcar.com/delivery/minisite/show/12612/id/957752

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: I have created a simple html page with your code and test it in Chrome. It raises several errors while loading some txt files. You should make a workable web page before trying to integrate it into the WebView.

Comment: if I try this HTML in online tools (http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/) everything shows up including the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it doesn't work because the following script in not correctly added to your html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//media.flixcar.com/delivery/static/inpage/9/js/lazy.js"></script>
```

It is dynamically added by the script `http://media.flixcar.com/delivery/static/inpage/9/js/append.js`.

The url should be `http://media.flixcar.com/delivery/static/inpage/9/js/lazy.js` so as be correctly loaded by the webview (which is nothing else than Edge browser).

I also think that you need to update each image attributes. Currently they are added also without protocol which are not supported by all browsers (for me it only works with Chrome).

```
<div class="flix-feature-image">
    <img src="//media.flixcar.com/delivery/static/mobile/standard/img/loading_icon.gif"
        data-srcset="//media.flixcar.com/f360cdn/Samsung-1601328499-id-feature-uhd-ju6600-ua65ju6600kpxd-52938564 2x, //media.flixcar.com/f360cdn/Samsung-1601328499-id-feature-uhd-ju6600-ua65ju6600kpxd-52938564 770w">
</div>
```

Adding protocol will fix the issue:

```
<div class="flix-feature-image">
    <img src="http://media.flixcar.com/delivery/static/mobile/standard/img/loading_icon.gif"
        data-srcset="http://media.flixcar.com/f360cdn/Samsung-1601328499-id-feature-uhd-ju6600-ua65ju6600kpxd-52938564 2x, http://media.flixcar.com/f360cdn/Samsung-1601328499-id-feature-uhd-ju6600-ua65ju6600kpxd-52938564 770w">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Arnaud. Is it possible for us to fix this like inserting protocol to all the requests or is it better to ask them to fix it?

Comment: I think you can modify your page by importing the lazy.js directly in your html content. You will also have to include jquery.js based on my tests. Then, your can make a function that loop through all images adding the http:// prefix to all `src` and `data-srcset` attributes. After this, try to call the event `lazyshow` event (declared in lazy.js) on `img` elements. With all this steps, I think it could work :)